# NoLock in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am trying to read the records from table even when the table is locked due to particular transaction.

**I am using below code**

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<String, List<Om_Category>>> CategoryList(Om_Category obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions 
                { 
                    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
                },
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            using (var categoryContext = new ModelGeneration())
            {

                categoryContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var data = await categoryContext
                    .tblCategory
                    .ToListAsync();

                transaction.Complete();

                return new KeyValuePair<String, List<Om_Category>>("", data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<String, List<Om_Category>>(ex.Message, null);
    }
}
```

> But seems like I am missing something to implement NoLocks. Still it
>   show timeout. Am I missing something ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx is worth a read. MS now recommend `categoryContext.Database.BeginTransaction` rather than TransactionScope. BeginTransaction accepts an isolation level, so you can pass in ReadUncommitted. I don't know whether this will solve your issue, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly Entity Framework inbuilt Transaction Class worked !!

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<String, List<BE_Category>>> CategoryList(BE_Category obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (var categoryContext = new ModelGeneration())
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = categoryContext
                      .Database
                      .BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                categoryContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                //Code

                dbContextTransaction.Commit();

                return new KeyValuePair<String, List<BE_Category>>("", data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<String, List<BE_Category>>(ex.Message, null);
    }
}
```

**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)**